# how to calculate Asymmetric shapes area in python with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

i need to calculate area of Asymmetric shapes like image below

[image]

this code read image and convert it to gray and find the shap countour 
i need to find out the area of the Asymmetric shapes

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread("download.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)


# find contours in the edge map
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(image,cnts, 0, (255, 0, 0), 8)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: How about cv2.contourArea(contour) ?

Comment: cv2.contourArea(contour)  returns just the contour line around the shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code and found that it didn't find contour of the shape. It's because you did `cv2.findContours` in gray image. The image should be a binary image, so I used `cv2.threshold`. Then the area can be calculate using `cv2.contourArea`.

Below is the code and the result.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

im, cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image,cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))


cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

>> 8656.0
>> 3824.5
```

[image]